# Start a new release within a existing release pipeline

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

At the end of our release pipeline we deploy to "PROD" like most people.  However, sometimes we have to hold the release until our customer is ready for it.  While we are waiting, we want to move forward and begin a new release pipeline so that testing can begin on the next release.  What is the best way to handle this since for a given release, only one can be active at a time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I can solve my problem by putting a Queuing policies on the PROD stage. Here is a link for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#queuing-policies